# Where is the primary key in the Cosmos DB GUI?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Azure CosmosDB NoSQL. I have created a new account and a new Cosmos DB. I'm following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-get-started). I can't seem to find the `config.key` as it is in the image:

[image]

I guess it is not an up to date tutorial.  What I have:

[image]

I have found the URI (which is not in the keys section), but where is the primary key?

Comment: The second picture you provided is `CosmosDb for Mongodb API`. And the cosmosdb with `Core(sql) `is correspond with the first picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have pointed out, you use Azure CosmosDB NoSQL while the first picture is [`Core (SQL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-get-started#create-azure-cosmos-db-account) type of account.

[image]

And the second picture you provided is using `Azure Cosmos Db for Mongo DB API` in API attribute. So, to connect Mongo DB, you just need to use [`Primary Connection String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-nodejs#configure-the-connection-string-in-your-nodejs-application).

[image]